# Dynamic loader: Strange behavior (Debian 8)

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library

I'm trying to setup and run a scientific application on Debian 8 guest OS (OpenVZ containerized environment). Since the OS-bundled GNU C++ library is quite old and doesn't contain all needed symbols, I have created a special directory to contain newer version of `libstdc++.so.6` and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to that directory. Also, I have made sure that the target application does not have SUID permission set (since, in that case, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` could be ignored on some platforms). Despite all that, `ldd <APP_EXECUTABLE>` command still shows that it uses default system location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is being ignored?

P.S. I have also tried using `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, but it was ignored as well.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what the case on debian 8 was, but with older gcc/binutils version it was the case that `--enable-new-dtags` was not the default and the  `DT_RPATH` burnt into the binary would override any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can check with `readelf -a <your_binary_or_so> | egrep 'RPATH|RUNPATH'`.

Comment: @mosvy Thank you. The `readelf` command that you suggested produces the following output: `0x000000000000000f (RPATH)    Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib]`. If I understand correctly, a set `RPATH` implies that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not applicable. I've read that a set `RPATH` could be changed by using `chrpath`. Would it be a feasible solution in my case?

Comment: @mosvy ... Or, perhaps, an even easier solution would be to create a symlink in `<APP_DIR/lib>`, pointing to the shared library version, containing required symbols. What do you think?

Comment: The latter would be a better solution.

Comment: @mosvy I just tested it. Unfortunately, for some reason, it didn't work as expected (still links default system library). Any thoughts on why that might be the case?

Comment: No idea, it should work. It certainly does in my testing. strace it, run ldd on it. Maybe the symlink you created is broken.

Comment: @mosvy All right. I will investigate further. Your prompt help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the standard system library directories (usually `/lib` and `/usr/lib`) and any directories defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and/or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` files are examined by the `ldconfig` command and the results are cached in `/etc/ld.so.cache`. The `ldconfig` command is normally run automatically by the package management tools whenever you install or remove library packages.

The dynamic loader uses this cache to speed up finding the required libraries whenever a new program is loaded.

If you add or remove symlinks within system library directories manually, you will most likely have to run `ldconfig` as root afterwards to make the system refresh the cache and so make your changes effective. Without running that command, the dynamic loader will have no clue that the library paths have changed, and will happily keep using the library paths from the old cache.

Although the above is essentially the basic mechanism for looking up libraries, it can be overridden by using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`(= "check these library directories first") or `LD_PRELOAD`(= "*always* load this library first) environment variables.

It is also possible to embed library path information into the program binary itself, using section attributes named `DT_RPATH` (deprecated) or `DT_RUNPATH`. These will also override the cache mechanism, but as far as I know their use is fairly unusual, *precisely* because it tends to lead into problems like the original question when you need a program to work in a system/environment that is no longer an **exact** match of the system the program was developed for.

Comment: nope, using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the `DT_RPATH` / `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic section attributes will override `/etc/ld.so.cache`, please read the order in the `ld.so(8)` manpage.

Comment: the OP had tried to create a link in the `$ORIGIN/../lib` path pointed by the binary's `DT_RPATH` and, for some reason, it didn't work (or at least that's my understanding of it).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (+1 for desire to help). However, it seems that @mosvy is correct in that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `DT_RPATH / DT_RUNPATH` attributes override loader cache. @mosvy: Your understanding of my symlink solution attempt is correct as well. Later today, I plan to try the `chrpath` solution. Even though it's less elegant, I'm afraid that it might be the only feasible approach at this time (I still plan to investigate why my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$ORIGIN/../lib` symlink solutions didn't work).

Comment: I think that I might have figured out the reason why my original two approaches did not work. It seems that I accidentally/somehow deployed a 32-bit version of GNU C++ library on a 64-bit system, which, obviously, loader was not happy about ... :-) Now, the challenge is to make sure that I install the newer version of the library in a safe way (to maintain the original / OS-bundled version intact). I guess, I will just download a relevant `.deb` package, install it locally (not system-wide) and try either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or symlink approach.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate the comments of @mosvy ... but accidentally mixing in a 32-bit library package on otherwise fully 64-bit system may indeed cause some confusion and unhappiness. However, I think Debian 8 can deal with 64/32 bitness using the multiarch mechanism: you can run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system, if the necessary 32-bit libraries are available. But you can never satisfy a library requirement of a 64-bit program with a 32-bit library, or vice versa.

Comment: @telcoM Thank you for the update and comment above. I agree with your thoughts.